# Create DLL of Python class using Visual studio 2013

Tags: python, dll

I am very new on python programming, I created python class using visual studio 2013, I need to create DLL of my python application, So I can use this class in my .Net application using python assembly.

It is possible to create DLL using Visual studio for python application?

Thanks,